# Combining two transparent UIImages?

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

I am trying to combine two transparent UIImages using the following code:

```
UIImage* image1;
UIImage* image2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( image1.size );

[ image1 drawInRect: CGRectMake( 0, 0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height ) ];
[ image2 drawInRect: CGRectMake( 0, 0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height ) ];

UIImage* combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The alpha is combined correctly, but the color is not preserved.  Because the CGContext initially has a black color (even though having 0 alpha) the resulting UIImage shifts towards black wherever image1 or image2 is transparent.  How can this be resolved?  I experimented with different blend modes without success.

Comment: you can set the colour of context...

Comment: Do you mean set the color of the entire context?  Ideally, I'd like to keep things background color neutral. For example, drawing the combined image on a black or white back ground would look correct.

Comment: Yes i mean set the colour of entire context.